# Want to download list of html files reachable from homepage

Tags: shell, posix, wget

I'm cleaning up an overgrown website, and I want to create a list of html files (webpages) that can be reached from the home page.  I don't want to download the files themselves, just their pathnames.

Is there some combination of options to wget, possibly redirecting the output files, but not the log info, to /dev/null that can do this?   I looked at the wget man page, and it looks alarmingly complicated.  What I want to do is simple.

Can anyone suggest how to get a list of html files reachable from the root, on a website?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test it right now, but maybe the `--spider` option might be useful?

Answer (score 0):

This works in my tests:

```
wget -r -l 1 -A html --delete-after -nd https://yoururl.com 2>&1 | grep '^--' | cut -d' ' -f4- | uniq
```